# AC rectifier and voltage regulator

Tags: led, voltage, voltage-regulator, ac, rectifier

I'm a mechanical engineer and my knowledge of electronics is letting me down please help. I'm looking to run a 1.5V led from an input signal that can vary from 0.3 to 0.5V ac. I want to make the entire circuit as small as possible. Up to now i found i probably need a full bridge rectifier with a capacitor over it connected to a small voltage regulator like a transistor regulator. Would this work? any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: You have a 0.3 to 0.5 Volt supply, and you want to get an output greater than 1.5 Volt from it (for the LED), without any additional power source?

Comment: What level of current can this source supply? (Is it an audio signal?)

Comment: What is the frequency of the signal? Is it a sinewave or square wave?

Answer (score 1):

A small 1:5 transformer will boost the voltage to the 1.5 to 2.5 V range, which will be enough to light up the LED. A current-limiting series resistor may or may not be needed, but just to be safe, make it 100 Ω to limit the current to 10 mA or so.

The LED can withstand the reverse voltage, so no other rectification should be necessary, but if you're really worried about it, just put an ordinary signal diode in parallel with the LED, pointing the other way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOAjd2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Dave. Could I use a capacitor on top of that to level out the signal and keep the brightness of the led steady? kind regards

Comment: No, a capacitor can't be inserted into the circuit that I've drawn. If you need one, then you'll also need a rectifier, and you'll also need more voltage out of the transformer in order to overcome the forward voltage of the rectifier.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: Of course, it is stated in the question.

Comment: @DaveTweed Hmm, I was hesitant about this since the question states "*that can vary from 0.3 to 0.5V ac*", which _could_ mean a slow variation merely between +0.3 and +0.5 Volts, i.e. some kind of unspecified frequency sensor input with a 0.2 Volt peak-to-peak value biased to 0.4 Volts. However, I can see that your view is fully tenable.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: Yes, in fact, in another comment (since deleted), the OP stated that it is the audio signal from an iPhone headphone jack.

Comment: @DaveTweed Uh ohh... so output impedance becomes a concern, as does maximum available power.